# How can I get rid of or purify the Crimson?

Tags: terraria

So it seems that in some worlds, the Crimson will automatically replace the Corruption.  Luckily/Unluckily for me, I seem to have only the Crimson in my world, and no Corruption.

That said, how do I get rid of the Crimson stone blocks to get to the Crimson Hearts scattered around the map?  I know that for the Corruption, you would need *Purification Powder* to do so, but to re-add it back in, you would need *Vile Powder*.  Does the same hold true for the Crimson? Or is there some other way I must go to break through Crimson rock?

Comment: Worlds will only ever have one or the other. You cannot have both Crimson and Corruption.

Comment: I'm confused though, the wiki states that after defeating the Wall of Flesh, two diagonal lines appear in the world, one hollow, the other corruption.  Would this in this case be replaced with crimson? The only time I beat the WoF was before 1.2 came out.

Comment: Yes, in some worlds, Crimson 100% replaces corruption. So from 1.2 on, anything that references corruption in the wiki is also talking about Crimson. Except for enemies and drops. Those change. But anything in general that happens to corruption (like beating the WoF) is the same for both.

Comment: You can not use "Purfication Powder" on crimson to remove it. I spent 50 silver on it and it did nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is not the most accessible way to do it, the *easiest* way is to use the **[Clentaminator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clentaminator)** with [Green Solution](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Green_Solution).

The more accessible ways are to use the **[Purification Powder](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Purification_Powder)** from a [Dryad](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad), **bomb** the Crimson with anything that breaks blocks when it explodes or mine it with a **pickaxe** (power 65% or higher, or in terms of tools: nightmare/deathbringer pickaxe or better).

Comment: What percent scale are you using for pickaxes?  Is that a gold pickaxe, or stronger?

Comment: @Zibbobz Nightmare pickaxe, Deathbringer pickaxe and Molten pickaxe are the only pre-hardmode pickaxes over 65%, all the hardmode pickaxes (and drills) are over that limit. You could also say "stronger than demonic/crimson".

Comment: You may want to include that in the answer, since it's not immediately obvious (I'm not sure if percentage power is listed next to a weapon when you hold it.  If it actually is, disregard this suggestion).

Comment: @Zibbobz It is listed on the weapon, but added it to make it clear.

Answer (score 7):

The same methods you use to break through Corruption should work just as well in the Crimson.  Bear in mind, however, that the Crimson's tunnels are oriented in diagonals, like long veins, so when getting deep into it, you should take this into consideration.

You could start your project by blocking it off with a wall.  Make it 6 tiles long, since I've  seen varying reports on how far Crimson can reach, and make it deep enough to block any Crimson grass that might reach beneath the earth.  10 tiles down will probably be plenty.

Purifcation powder should work well for breaking through Crimson blocks, but Dynamite and other explosions will also work (not grenades) if you haven't got the Dryad yet.

Also keep in mind that if you're going to be breaking the special 'orbs' (Crimson Hearts now I think) in the Crimson, you'll be dealing with Brain of Cthulhu instead of the Eater of Worlds.  So be prepared for a new boss.

And, as 3ventic says, a pickaxe of 65% power or greater (nightmare/deathbringer pickaxe or better) can cut through Crimson.

Read more [here](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/The_Crimson).

Comment: A link to the Terraria wiki article on this subject would make this answer very good.

Comment: Can't access the wiki at this moment from this computer unfortunately.  Or I would include said link.  Anyone with a 2,000+ reputation, feel free to pin it on.

Comment: Sadly I don't either.

Answer (score -2):

Use Clentaminator with green powder and spray it on the crimson and Boom gone. Or use purification powder bought from the "dryad".

Answer (score -2):

if you already made it to hard mode in your world is gone is its pat 3% you need to pack your things and make a new world get the clementinator and a lot of green solution and cure your world before you unlock hard mode sorry about your npcs there goners :(

Answer (score -3):

The only way is to defeat the wof then kill a mech boss then make a house then the steampunker will move in so you can buy the machine and green solution so you can spray it on the crimson